# Does Mobile Skype clients Android support initiating/hosting conference calls

Tags: android, call, skype

I trying to make a group audio call from my android application using Skype. My code snippet is:

```
// Create the Intent from our Skype URI.
Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,"skype:joyal.test;joyal.test2?call");
myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
myContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```

By calling above lines it creates a Skype group with the users mentioned in Uri and initiate the call, and automatically the call ends suddenly. I tried various methods, getting the same response - the call is disconnecting automatically.

I need to host the Skype group call from my application in Android.

Comment: @ thepoosh- I need to initiate a group call from my app. " Launch Skype from an App Programmatically & Pass Number - Android " point out one by one call functionality. It will be great if you guide me in right path and avoid the down vote for duplication

Comment: I see thepoosh is right. Just copy paste the code in the sampled link. The official skype docs say you construct the group just by adding more participants, please read there on url formating https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745882.aspx

Comment: @eduyayo- I tried the with sample code itself and follow as per the official skype docs. "Mobile Skype clients (iOS and Android) do not support initiating/hosting conference calls." saying in url which you given above- msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745882.aspx. But the same conference call done in iOs application, but in android it automatically disconnecting and other user getting a notification for group creating.